# Why/How does this scala contravariant example work?

Tags: scala

This code seems to set up  a contravariant example: FruitBox can take in Apples or Oranges.

```
class Fruit(name: String) { }
case class Apple(name: String) extends Fruit(name) {}
case class Orange(name: String) extends Fruit(name) {}

class Box[-T] {
  type U >: T
  def put(t: U): Unit= {box += t}
  val box = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[U]()
}

  object test {
   val FruitBox = new Box[Fruit]
   // Fruit Box takes in everything
   FruitBox.put(new Fruit("f1"))
   FruitBox.put(new Orange("o1"))
   FruitBox.put(new Apple("a1")) 

   // and Orange Box takes in only oranges
    val OrangeBox = new Box[Orange]
     //OrangeBox.put(new Apple("o2")  ==> Compile Error that makes sense
    OrangeBox.put(new Orange("o2"))

   // Contra-variant nature is also demonstrated by
     val o: Box[Orange] = FruitBox 
  }
```

That is all fine...but *why* does it work ? specifically:
1. When the FruitBox is initialized,  why does the "type U >: T" not constrain it to supertypes of Fruit? In spite of that constraint,  the FruitBox is able to put the  subtypes if Fruit ( oranges and apples )...how?

Comment: Sounds like you want covariance and not contravariance. `type U >: T` means that `U` can be bounded _below_ by `T`. It doesn't need to be a subtype at all.

Comment: I don't understand. I like the behavior of the code above: a FruitBox that can put apples and oranges, and an OrangeBox that can only put oranges.  That looks like contra-variant behavior, and I am fine with it. But why does it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, while Scala allows you to write `new Box[Fruit]`, leaving `U` an abstract member, I don't understand why. <s>However, Scala seems to assume `U = T` in this case. Since your code never implements `U`, it can just be replaced by `T`. So you end up with `def put(t: Fruit)` in `FruitBox`: of course it accepts `Apple`s, since they are `Fruit`s!</s> The only thing Scala knows about `U` is that it's a supertype of `T`; thus `T` is a subtype of `U`, and so is every subtype of `T`. So any subtype of `Fruit` can be passed to `FruitBox.put`. So `def put(t: U): Unit` is effectively the same as `put(t: T): Unit` unless you implement `U` as in `new Box[Fruit] { type U = Object }`.

> a FruitBox that can put apples and oranges, and an OrangeBox that can only put oranges. That looks like contra-variant behavior, and I am fine with it.

It isn't at all contravariant behavior; you'll get exactly the same with

```
class Box[T] {
  def put(t: T): Unit= {box += t}
  val box = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[T]()
}
```

Comment: Actually, with your `Box[T]` mod the `val o: Box[Orange] = FruitBox` line fails to compile. Which might not be a bad thing as it currently allows a `Box[Orange]` to contain `Apple("a1")`.

Comment: Yes, _that's_ contravariant behavior; I was saying that "a FruitBox that can put apples and oranges, and an OrangeBox that can only put oranges" isn't.

Comment: It's apparently OK to leave type members abstract, you can say just `type U` and it still compiles (but you cannot use `put` and `box` members)

Comment: @n.m. Yes, it is. What I don't understand is _why_ it is allowed. However, I should have phrased it differently.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov i don't understand your comment "he only thing Scala knows about U is that it's a supertype of T; thus T is a subtype of U, and so is every subtype of T. So any subtype of Fruit can be passed to FruitBox.put"..  The way I visualize it., when FruitBox gets imitialized, the code looks like "class Box[Fruit] , type U >: Fruit , def put (t: U)..." that would suggest only superTypes of Fruit be allowed.. What am I missing?

Comment: @user7938511 If you had just `put(f: Fruit)`, you can pass any subtype of `Fruit` as well, right? And if you had `put(f: Object)`, you can pass `Fruit` and any subtype of `Fruit`, because they are all subtypes of `Object`. So here you have `put(f: some unknown supertype of Fruit)`, you can also pass `Fruit` and any subtype of `Fruit`, but you can't pass any proper supertype, because `U` could be `Fruit` itself.

Comment: "why it is allowed" why not? There's nothing dangerous in allowing it. See also http://typelevel.org/blog/2015/07/13/type-members-parameters.html

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I am beginning to get it now. I had misunderstood  "U>:T" as putting a constraint on the incoming argument...it is really a constraint on the left hand side of the assignment.

Comment: @n.m. "Type members are [almost] type parameters" Right, and this argues the other way: you can write `val x = new Blah` but you can't write `val x = new Blah2` or even `val x = new Blah2[_]`, you need `val x = new Blah2[SomeType]`.

Answer (score 0):

To complement @AlexanderRomanov's answer Scala treats `U >: T` as an existential type `_ >: T`. Basically it materializes to `T` when you actually specify it:

```
val orangeBox = new Box[Orange]
```

Btw, another more conventional way to do it is to implement `U` in subclass:

```
trait Box[-T]{
  type U >: T
}

class BoxImpl[T] extends Box[T]{
  type U = T
}
```

So, if you used type parameter instead of type member, the code would be like:

```
class Box[T, _ >: T]
val orangeBox = new Box[Orange, Orange]
```

In your case Scala just finds appropriate type for you in order to "materialize" that existential.

The only inconsistency here is that it actually doesn't allow:

```
class BoxImpl[-T] extends Box[T]{
  type U = T
}
//error: contravariant type T occurs in invariant position in type T of type U
```

So basically when you're instantiating your `Box[Orange]` it ignores `-T` as in `class BoxImpl[T] extends Box[T]` (regardless that original `Box` had `-T`)